# FCM Data Transfer pending - Transfer deferred due to source data not being available

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have linked FCM to BigQuery and the data has started flowing nicely, however since Monday the DT keeps going into a pending state and contain the following message
"Transfer deferred due to source data not being available".

Does anyone know what is going on and what can be done to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Any updates here, facing this problem and cannot find anything related to that online

Answer (score 1):

The same error i encountered, data exported after i bound credit card.
[big-query sandbox have some limits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFrvS.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).